# Add data to Python list directly from database

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I have a Python list with locations in my script which I added manually. And I have a DB called Budget.db which already has 50+locations.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/Administrator/project/BUDGET.db')

locationList = [
'Aberdeen; Aberdeen Airport',
'Belfast; Belfast International Airport Aldergrove',
'Belfast; George Best Belfast City Airport',
'Birmingham; Terminal Building',
'Blackpool; Blackpool Airport',
'Bristol; Bristol Airport',
'Cardiff; Meet And Greet Only',
'Edinburgh; Car Rental Centre',
'Exeter; Exeter Airport',
'Glasgow; Glasgow International Airport',
]
```

My question is, how can I add the 50+ locations from my DB into my Python list ? Or it would be even better if the whole list is imported from the DB instead of me doing it manually. Thx appreciate the help

```
Database name : Budget.db
Table name : Locations
Column name : Name (TEXT)
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). If yes, what is left unclear? If no, do it.

Comment: Sorry not that technical sound yet, thats why I hoped for some samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just query and collect

```py
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/Administrator/project/BUDGET.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

try:
    results = [
        row[0]
        for row in cursor.execute("SELECT Name FROM Locations").fetchall()
    ]
finally:
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```